# {"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1","title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId"

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, web-applications

I am trying to create a site using my web api. Everything went fine with simple GET function. But when i created a POST method and added a razor page to it, any time i try to open that page i get the same message: {"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1","title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"00-b6df63a1f0833724ea5e9547634bec47-0bc084ebe01d4967-00","errors":{"workerId":["The value 'register' is not valid."]}}. The code works when using swagger.
WorkerController fragmet for registration:

```
[HttpPost("register")]
        [ProducesResponseType(204)]
        [ProducesResponseType(400)]
        public IActionResult Register(Worker workerCreate)
        {
            if (workerCreate == null)
                return BadRequest(ModelState);

            var worker = _workerRepository.GetWorkers()
                .Where(x => x.Email.Trim().ToUpper() == workerCreate.Email.ToUpper()
                || x.PhoneNum.Trim().ToUpper() == workerCreate.PhoneNum.ToUpper())
                .FirstOrDefault();

            if (worker != null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Worker already exists");
                return StatusCode(422, ModelState);
            }

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            

            if (!_workerRepository.Register(workerCreate))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Something went wrong while saving");
                return StatusCode(500, ModelState);
            }

            return Ok("Successfully registered");
        }
```

Code of WorkerController in Web Application:

```
public IActionResult Register()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register(WebApplicationWorker worker)
        {

            var apiUrl = "https://localhost:7071/api/Worker/register";
            worker.Id = 0;

            string jsonPayload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(worker);
            HttpContent content = new StringContent(jsonPayload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            using (var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(apiUrl, content))
            {
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Workers");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Ошибка регистрации");
                }
            }
            return View(worker);
        }
```

Code of WebApplicationWorkerModel:

```
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace CourseWorkZakharov.Web.Models
{
    public class WebApplicationWorker
    {
        [JsonIgnore]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNum { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Degree { get; set; }
        public string WorkExp { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string ImagePath { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Code of Register page:

```
@model WebApplicationWorker

<h1>Регистрация пользователя</h1>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Worker", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LastName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PhoneNum)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PhoneNum)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Degree)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Degree)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.WorkExp)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.WorkExp)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Description)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Description)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ImagePath)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ImagePath, new { type = "file" })
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
    </div>

    <button type="submit">Зарегистрироваться</button>
}
```

Huge thanks in advance

I have tried removing the main part of the code (under [HttpPost]) and emptying the page. didn't help at all

Comment: From the error message, you post the request the `workerId` property with value: "register"? But it seems there is no `workerId` property in your model class.

Comment: yep, thats another trick, i have no workerId property, but the program decides that i do. I have it in some other models but they are not called here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of research I managed to find a "tick" who is causing all the mischief. The bastard was in my WorkerController of my API
`

[HttpGet("{workerId}")]

```
    [ProducesResponseType(200, Type = typeof(Worker))]
    [ProducesResponseType(400)]
    public IActionResult GetWorker(int workerId)
    {
        if(!_workerRepository.WorkerExists(workerId))
            return NotFound();
        var worker = _workerRepository.GetWorker(workerId);
        if (worker == null)
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        return Ok(worker);
    }`
```

because its route is "api/Worker/{workerId}" and register route is "api/worke/register" program took it as i was passing "register" as workerId